# We Cannot publish on the PlayStore an app with an Open App Ads on launch

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, admob, google-play-console

We face on issue with the Google PlayStore along Open App ads usage. The PlayStore reject all of ours apps which try to display an Open App Ads after launch.

Scenario :

User launch the app (app was not in the background, it's a cold start) -> native splash screen is display -> we launch Open App Ads -> close native splash screen -> show app home page.

PlayStore team reject us with the following message :

> We found that your app contains code that implements ads on button clicks, which interferes with the normal use of the application

Open App Ad are not triggered by any buttons as the flow above show. However, we seems to have found that it's because of the Android Back Button. This Back button was disabled by the Admob Team during an Open App Ad display and that seems to be the source of the rejection.

We contacted The Admob Team and they confirmed to us that the Back button was well disabled by them. They asked us also to contact the PlayStore team to share that to them and to try to get a clear explanation of the issue.

Here is the problem: the PlayStore team continue to respond to us with the same "automatic" message and "refuse" to give us more details and also refuse to answer to all of our questions...

I'm here to ask if someone has well succeed to implement an Open App Ad on Android on app launch (cold start) without a PlayStore rejection? The PlayStore team affirmed that we were the alone with this "issue".